# pandas dataframe from array of nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

```
import pandas as pd
input_thing = [
    [{'foo': 1, 'bar': 'a', }], 
    [{'foo': 2, 'bar': 'b', }],
]
print(input_thing)
```

How can I get a nice pandas dataframe out of the data displayed above?
I.e. that the columns `foo` and `bar` are nicely displayed on the outside

```
 pd.DataFrame(input_thing)
```

Only will generate a dataframe with a single column 0

The desired output would be:

```
pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame(input_thing[0]),
    pd.DataFrame(input_thing[1])
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If every sublist in `input_thing` has one element:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([i[0] for i in input_thing])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   foo bar
0    1   a
1    2   b
```

---

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(input_thing)
print(df[0].apply(pd.Series))
```

Prints:

```
   foo bar
0    1   a
1    2   b
```

Comment: Sure - but is there also a vectorized way?

Comment: @GeorgHeiler See my edit. I added a version with `pd.Series`

Comment: I'm certain `df.apply(pd.Series)` is very slow compared to list comprehension as it builds `Series` object for each item in the list which adds way too much overhead. Your better off using list comprehension.

Comment: To be sure I timeit'd with list of list 20k... List comprehension -> 14.2 ms... `df[0].apply(pd.Series)` -> 6.66 s

Comment: @Ch3steR You beat me to it :)... I was going to do some `timeit` test.

Comment: @AndrejKesely haha :P You could also do `pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(input_thing))` too. Anyways nice one.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your pd.concat with a for loop:

```
import pandas as pd
input_thing = [
[{'foo': 1, 'bar': 'a', }], 
[{'foo': 2, 'bar': 'b', }],
]
df = pd.DataFrame([i[0] for i in input_thing])
print(df)
```

Then it will get what you want:

```
    foo bar
0    1   a
1    2   b
```

This is what you desire.

Comment: It's the same as andrej's answer. Duplicate answers don't help the community. If you have an alternate answer you can add that.

Comment: I just want to emphasize to use a loop to replace the pd.concat.